Why is this happening with the Bevel tool?
Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here? The outer bevel's are fine, but the inner is creating a triangle.
When I tried adding more sub dividers it becomes 'blocked', deforming the bevel, so it's not as round as the others.

The shape I'm trying to trace

The file


Well, the vertices/edges where these vertical and horizontal inner edges are connected to get split up. What do you expect how hey should behave? To which of the new vertices should they connect to?

I see, so what would be the best way to get the bevel on the one I'm having an issue with? The issue stems from me extending the plane as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/Tjtc7Rp.png

The problem here are the inner edges connecting to the ones that get beveled. You can do the following:

Select all those edges that are unnecessary for the shape.


Press X and choose Dissolve Edges.


Now the inner edges should be gone, but the shape still the same and you can select the edges to bevel.


Now the edges get beveled without any inner edges.



This is a method if you want to select which edges you want to get rid of. In your case, where you simply can remove everything that is not a right angle, you can do it quicker like this:

Select all with A.


Press X and choose Limited Dissolve.


This way Blender gets rid of all vertices, edges etc. which are below a certain threshold angle. The default is 5°, which is often too much for detailed rounded meshes, but since your angles are all 90° or 0°, that's okay. But you can change the Max Angle value in the tool options at the bottom left of the viewport.



Afterwards you can bevel like before.

Thank you, I'm a newbie and did not think it'd be that simple! lesson learnt

@Caz You could also select the three faces on the side and press F which makes a single face of them. But if you want to remove the edges on the sides, top and back you would have to select them separately and repeat the merging process for the different sides, you cannot do all at once. And it will leave the vertices belonging to the edges behind (which you could then dissolve as well, but then you can do it right from the start). Oh, I'll add a quicker method as well.
